# Is there an alternative to Node.js for creating a Rails 6 application?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails-6, rhino

The "Getting Started" Guide from Rails says you need to have Node.js installed as well as Yarn. Is there an alternative for the Node.js JavaScript runtime like Rhino?

Answer (score 2):

Rails 6 is using webpack to compile js and css files and in order for webpack to work Node is mandatory and by default they are using Yarn but you can change it to NPM if you wish

Comment: No way around Node.js ?